# iPad: Disable Today View (Home/Lock screen left-edge swipe) completely?

Tags: ipad, widgets, lockscreen

I am currently on iPadOS 15.6.1. Tell me if I am missing something but I have no idea why I would want to swipe from the left edge each time to open some sort of drawer to see widgets, when I can just place the same widgets on the Home Screen and see them without swiping.

I have removed all the default widgets from Today View, so it currently shows only "(Edit)" on a blurred background. But I often invoke it by mistake. Can I disable this left drawer (Today View) completely from the Home/Lock Screen? That is, I want nothing to happen, when I swipe from the left edge to the right on the Home/Lock Screen.

- Example of "Today View" from Apple's website.
  [image]